# Best practice for class field having different values in subclasses

Tags: java

I have some abstract class, in one of its method I use a string field which is supposed to be specific to the subclasses. I wonder what is the bect practice to implemnet this? via field and setting the field value in a consructors of the subclasses? via a static field and changing the value in every subclass?

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The subclasses should specify the value. The superclass should define it's interface. Use the [template method design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Example:

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
  public abstract String getSomeValue();

  public void method() {
     String s = getSomeValue();
  }
}


public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
  private static final String CONSTANT = "";

  public String getSomeValue() {
    return CONSTANT;
  }
}
```

Another option is to set it in the constructor:

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
  private String value;

  public SuperClass(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}


public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
  private static final String CONSTANT = "";

  public SubClass() {
    super(CONSTANT);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The first option is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Jakub: If you use the first option, you should know that you should never call methods you believe are overridden (which abstract methods most certainly are) from the constructor, as the subclass that defines the method isn't initialized when the superclass constructor is run.

Answer (score 9):

Static fields aren't overridable, so that's not an option.

The best way is giving the superclass a constructor that takes the string as an argument, so the subclasses don't forget "filling out" the value:

```
abstract class Super {
    final String blah;
    protected Super(String blah) {
        if (blah == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        this.blah = blah;
    }
    public String getBlah(){ return blah; }
}
class Sub extends Super {
    public Sub() { super("Sub"); }
}
```

Comment: ok, NPE should be IllegalArgumentException, but why is the protected constructor bad in your opinion?

Comment: Using NPE for null arguments is standard behavior in JDK, actually. Don't look at me, I'm just conforming.

Answer (score 1):

```
abstract class Base{
        String field ;
        public Base(String field){
            this.field = field;
        }
    }
class Sub extends Base{
    public Sub(String field){
        super(field);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to define an abstract get-method at the abstract super class/interface.

This way every subclass may implement its own way to fetch the property.

```
abstract class SuperClass {
  abstract String getBlah();
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass{
  String getBlah(){
    return "blubb";
  }
}
```